# Создание своих компонентов на modx

Tags: modx, php

Добрый день, всем! Подобрался к этапу созданию своих компонентов. Вопросы такие возникли:

1. Как правильно создавать свои компоненты на modx?
2. Каким образом можно компилировать архивы-дистрибутивы установщики компонентов?
3. Про modExtra тоже не совсем понял, что это за зверь такой, предусмотренный уже в Modx?

Читал эту статью http://habrahabr.ru/post/126635/, но так ничего работоспособного сделать не удалось, по той причине, что там больше половины скриптов просто отсутствовали. И второй нюанс, не понятно, как формировать архивы, которые можно потом установить на modx. Расскажите кто что знает по этой теме. Хотелось бы получить опыт от тех, кто этим занимался уже.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У того же Безумкина в блоге есть [пошаговое описание разработки компонента для рассылки](https://bezumkin.ru/training/course1/?page=2)

Comment: Да, спасибо, почитаю. Полезная инфа.